# API Key for GCM from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM using my own sever. Now I'm trying to do the same using Python 2.7 in Google App Engine. How can I get the IP address for the server hosting my app? (I need it for API Key). Is IP-LookUp only option? And if I do so will the IP address remain constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the IP easily by doing a ping from the command line to the domain name, as in "ping appspot.com". With this you will obtain the response from the real IP. Unfortunately this IP will change over time and won't make your GCM service work.

In order to make it work you only need to leave the allowed IPs field blank.

Comment: Superb man thank you! I thought that an IP is necessary for an API KEY to be generated and because App Engine has dynamic IPs i was really troubling with this. Thank you for this simple solution, i was already contemplating on making my own server with static IP :P.

Comment: But how secure is this? If I leave the IP field blank, does that not expose someone to vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

I used My own server to solve this. But better solution was to use [GCM4Public](http://gcm4public.appspot.com/)